# WebClient.UploadStringAsync does not POST data to the server correctly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am trying to post an email address and password to a server in order to receive JSON back. However the following code receives a response from the server indicating that the POST data was not received.

```
private void BtnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String email = Email.Text;
    String password = Password.Password;

    String data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.server.com/login");

    wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
    wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", data);
}
```

The string `data` is produced correctly in the format `email=test@test.com&password=hunter2`.

And the event handler function...

```
private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
}
```

What do I need to do to ensure the fields are posted to the server correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you forgot set header Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded if your server is expecting it?

Comment: Have you debugged what was transmitted, with a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: @RomanGolenok That did the trick! Thank you! And Rowland, I haven't used any tools like Fiddler but I will in the future - thank you!


`wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` and
`wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` in your code. This will post your data to server correctly.
See below code this will help u...

```cs
private void BtnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String email = Email.Text;
    String password = Password.Password;
    String data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.server.com/login");
    wc.UploadStringCompleted += new ploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
    wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", data);
}
```